# redirecting index.html to the root using httpd.conf

Tags: redirect, root, httpd.conf

I tried to redirect all index.html to root folder by configuring Apache webserver httpd.conf using settings below. It's able to redirect successfully, however it keeps pointing to testsite.com// instead of testsite.com/. Any idea why it kept forwarding to the url with 2 slash '/'? Appreciate your advice, Thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Nobody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

Remove that monstrosity and use:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

also for missing resources:

```
FallBackResource /index.html
```